# Export layer with symbology with open-source tool

Tags: open-source-gis, feature-layer

Similar to ArcGIS's "Layers", and "Layer packages", are there any open-source analogs? If I have a PostGIS table opened in QGIS (or GRASS, etc.), can I export it WITH the data, as well as with a symbology definition, etc.

I want to send a layer to someone that they can open in Arc/QGIS/GRASS/etc. which will retain the symbology and labeling that I setup on my end. Can this be stored within a PostGIS table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save style as SLD File or QGIS Layer Style File in QGIS from Style tab of layer properties dialogue. I don't know whether SVG markers are exported as well or they need to be attached to a layer being sent.